# using directshow with a camera in matlab. Mightex camera

Tags: matlab, camera, directshow

I have camera BTE-B050-U
and I want to Access it using matlab (I'll have to write some kind of gui in the end)
the problem is that I have no idea how to access it.
The support doesn't know matlab but said to look at the SDK in this file using directshow
http://www.mightexsystems.com/images/File/buffered_camera_software_release_4download.zip
I have no idea even how to contact the camera in matlab. I searched in this forum and after doing a command (the camera is installed)

> > imaqhwinfo

this is what i get:

Warning: No Image Acquisition adaptors found. Image acquisition adaptors may be
available as downloadable support packages. Open Support Package Installer to install
additional vendors.

ans =

```
InstalledAdaptors: {}
    MATLABVersion: '9.0 (R2016a)'
      ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
   ToolboxVersion: '5.0 (R2016a)'
```

Could anyone help please?

Thanks,

Eli

Comment: Try installing Support Package. See: [http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/image-acquisition-support-packages-for-hardware-adaptors.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/image-acquisition-support-packages-for-hardware-adaptors.html). In Matlab workspace, execute: `supportPackageInstaller`. Select "OS Generic Video Interface", and **hope** it works.

Comment: It's a stand alone without internet connection.
I'm also trying some other way and get a lot of errors:
cd('C:\buffered_camera_software_release_4download\SDK\Lib\x64')
libname='BUF_USBCamera_SDK'
loadlibrary(libname)
Warning: Warnings messages were produced while parsing.  Check the functions you
intend to use for correctness.  Warning text can be viewed using:
 [notfound,warnings]=loadlibrary(...) 

> In loadlibrary 
Error loading library intermediate output follows.
The actual error is at the end of this output.
*********

Comment: Failed to parse type '( __cdecl__ )) BUFUSB_InitDevice ( void' original input '( __cdecl__ )) BUFUSB_InitDevice ( void '
Found on line 52 of input from line 60 of fileC:\\buffered_camera_software_release_4download\\SDK\\Lib\\x64\\BUF_USBCamera_SDK.h
Error parsing argument for function __attribute__ function may be invalid.
Failed to parse type '( __cdecl__ )) BUFUSB_UnInitDevice ( void' original input '( __cdecl__ )) BUFUSB_UnInitDevice ( void '
Found on line 53 of input from line 61 of file C:\\buffered_camera_software_release_4download\\SDK\\Lib\\x64\\BUF_USBCamera_SDK.h

Comment: and more errors like it